# IF ELSE condition asp net with SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
string conn = "";

conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ToString();
SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);

objsqlconn.Open();

SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("IF (select 1 from PRODUCT where PRODUCT_NAME=" + Master_product_txt.Text + ")=1
    PRINT 'ALREADY AVAILABLE'
ELSE
    Insert into PRODUCT(PRODUCT_NAME) Values('" + Master_product_txt.Text + "')
GO", objsqlconn);

objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show("Details Successfully Added!!!");
```

I'm trying check the data base values before insert the value, I've wrote query for it, it's working in sql server environment, I could not able to implement same thing in Visual Studio

Comment: What do you mean by "could not able"? Is there an error message? Are you getting different results? Also, your code is very vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 5):

- `go` is a SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) statement, it won't work from C#
- use parameters to avoid SQL injection
- it is unusual to use the Hungarian `obj` prefix in C#

A quick try at a better version:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE PRODUCT_NAME = @NAME)
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO PRODUCT (PRODUCT_NAME) VALUES (@NAME)
        END
    ", sqlconn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", Master_product_txt.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: system throws ` InvalidOperationException ` on `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: @RJ10 look at the exception details, what does it say?

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: @RJ10: That means the second argument to `new SqlCommand(query, connection)` (the connection) is empty.   It should contain an open connection.

Comment: Yes, I noticed and open the connection also, `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.` but it seems syntax are okay..,

Answer (score 1):

```
     SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT 1 from PRODUCT WHERE PRODUCT_NAME=@NAME" , objsqlconn);
//NVarChar
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar,20).Value = Master_product_txt.Text;   
objsqlconn.Open();
        readr = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

        if (!readr.HasRows) 
        {
        `// code to insert values here.
        }`
```

PRINT 'ALREADY AVAILABLE' will not work here.For capturing print statement message you have to add an event handler to the InfoMessage event on the connection.And use parametrized query where ever possible. ;)

Comment: If you are going to correct his query you should fix the fact he did not use parameters too.

Comment: [You should not use AddWithValue when passing strings](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: Thanks you Sir for pointing it out, got something new to learn today. Guess I am more benefited by answering.